# Performance Issues RDP Session Server 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, rdp

i hope that you're very well todaay.

Again i'm posting here trying to find a solution for a very strange behavior of RDP Session.

I'm implementing a Server 2003 Image with MDT 2012. In the deployment process I'm implementing some KB's needed

I'll write the updates installed using the task sequence here:

KB923845 - BITS

KB958644

KB958687

KB982214

KB971468

KB2621440

KB2508429

Later, internally executes some customization process and after that all is ok except that when the people in the organization tries to connect to a remote desktop session, it works but the performance it is not the expected. Is too slow, every second when they tries to move a windows or open the task manager exists a lag about three o four seconds. However locally all is ok. I think that could be the image because we connect to another computers with the SAME OS in the SAME subnet from the same computer and that's not occurs.

Can you helpme?

Additional info: in two or  three situations, when the IT Manager tries to connect a RDP Session, the computer shows a bluscreen with this information: The driver is mismanaging System PTE's

Technical Information: STOP: 0x000000DA

I was checking the latest version of the driver and is the currently installed.

I hope that you can helpme!

Thanks!

;)

Additional info: we check the dmp files with WInDBG and we updated the video driver but the problem persists, only functions ok if we again made a sysprep process.

Comment: You know that 2003 is no longer supported by Microsoft ? Do you select to serialize in the sysprep ? For the bluescreen please update all driver and firmware first.

Comment: yes of course, we know that server 2003 is not supported. We dont choose generalize in the sysprep process, basically because exists a lot of compatibility issues when we do that, We are using a NewSID.exe tool from sysinternal to generate identifier and join the computer to the domain,

Comment: Users access from a WAN ? and run a gpresult under a slow account to be sure nothing apply to the user that can affect the session

Comment: no, the user connect in the same LAN. The computer does not have policies applied at the moment. It's a very strange behavior.

Comment: The computer does not have policy, but does the user got some ? as they will apply.

Comment: yeap, the computer and the user doe snot have policies applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a lot of testing, definitely the problem we caused because the image was not captured with Sysprep. We run sysprep and the process of recognition of the HAL allow us to connect to RDP sessions without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

> Bug Check 0xDA: SYSTEM_PTE_MISUSE
>
> The SYSTEM_PTE_MISUSE bug check has a value of 0x000000DA. This indicates that a page table entry (PTE) routine has been used in an improper way.

Use WinDBG and the parameters included with the bugcheck to identify the problematic driver. Although you say in your question that you updated your video driver, I see no evidence in your question that the video driver was actually the driver causing the problem.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560282%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

If the driver that is crashing the kernel is from a 3rd party vendor, contact the vendor and see if there's an update. Or, if the driver belongs to an optional component, then uninstall it. If the driver belongs to Microsoft, then:

`¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

There is no valid reason or excuse to be deploying Server 2003 at this point in time.

Comment: Thanks for your help, we know, there is no reason to support server 2003 :/